# Import local data files to ontology

Tags: owl, jena, ontology, protege

I am modeling an ontology in Protege that represents a manufacturing process and I want to create instances with my dataset that is in different formats (csv, xsl, CAD etc.) My question is if this can be solved with apache jena?

Comment: for CSV this was already retired from Jena, you need mappings from columns anyways: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/csv/

Comment: For Protege there is still mapping master, but this also needs your input to map from CSV columns to the corresponding RDF properties. For all other formats you have to look for parser and then use e.g. Apache Jena to create the RDF triples for each entry